# Can not change paper size on printer

Tags: printing

I try to change paper size from na_letter_8.5x11in to A4, but settings are not saved. When I press "Apply", the setting goes back to na_letter_8.5x11in.

The printer is a network connected Toshiba if that matters.

I go into the printer settings and press Job Options on the printer in question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It looks like CUPS overwrites any changes you make. So to fix this type in terminal:

```
sudo service cups stop
```

now you need to open */etc/cups/printers.conf* in text editor

```
sudo gedit /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

and change

```
option media na-letter
```

to

```
option media iso-a4
```

save your changes and start CUPS with the following command:

```
sudo service cups start
```

You should see your changes in the printer settings. I haven't found a way to change these settings without stopping CUPS.

Answer (score 0):

editing printers.conf didnt work for me.

I found the settings in system-config-printer. (ubuntu 12 gnome 3)

---

when i call system-config-printer, I get this window that I never seen before, but it has my printer
right click on printer -> Properties -> Printer Options -> Media size: changed to "A4".

Comment: Can you describe this more?