# Custom paper size = Processing - Not Connected?

Tags: printing

I am trying to print a custom paper size of `105.00 inches x 23.39 inches` (the [GLDT](http://futurist.se/gldt/) for my office :D). Whenever I try a custom paper size, the job sits in the queue with the message `Processing - Not Connected?`

If I print to a standard paper size, it prints no problem. I am printing to an `Epson Stylus Pro 9900` and have tried `IPP, LPD, and Socket 9100` works best, but still no go on custom paper size jobs with any of these. I have tried a variety of custom sizes. Printing is not a problem when selecting existing paper sizes. I am using the only available drivers which seem to be available Epson Stylus Pro 9900 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.8-pre1 and come in 12.04 no problem.

The only manual solution I can come up with is to edit the picture and make separate pages and print them out to scale as much as possible and piece them together...bleh.

Anyone aware of a fix? I did much rather have a working solution than manual labor. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/264651/169736

Comment: hm - it is difference about gimp 2.8 and gimp 3.x (upwards) ... gimp is eatening itself up like a cannibal zombie ... on dual-boot with windows.

Comment: @Braiam thanks, didn't help. Even when making my custom plotter size settings into a "standard/preset" format I could choose from. :(

Comment: long shot, but is that thing postscript compliant?  I had an old brother that would do the same thing.  Only way I resolved it was switching to a postscript driver.  (I'd look myself, but as it would seem, the Epson Americas site is down for maintenance)

Comment: @MattBarnes it looks like you are right. Supports Adobe Postscript 3 (source: http://www.epson.com/_alfresco/proimaging/products/StylusPro79009900efi/downloads/Epson-Proofing-Edition-Sales-Reference-Guide.pdf ) Write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

First, lets get to know what your printer will do:

```
$lpoptions -d <printer-name>
```

then assuming your printer can handle your desired resolution etc...
we can try to print. --What if is says it can only do 300DPI but you KNOW the printer can do more? well, maybe try reinstalling the printer with a better, more updated, non-generic driver. Then re-investigate the options that gives you.

now try giving the command:

```
$lp  -d <printer-name> -o PageSize=Custom.266x59cm <file.name>
```

Note: yeah, I know that 105'x23.39' isn't exactly 266x59cm but I'm not certain it will take decimals in there. I've also never tried using "in" for inches. it might exist, though I didn't read it in the manpages.

post results or errors.

Comment: It may be interesting to know the output of $df /var/spool  odd things can happen if spool overflows.